# Looking for Regex to validate MM/DD/YY HH:mm format

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm looking for a regular expression to use with an ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator control to check for the following format:

```
08/10/11 23:00
```

It must be `MM/DD/YY HH:mm` using a 24 hour clock. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: And do the Users settings play any role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This matches your spec, albeit a bit flexible.

```
/^(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])/(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:\d\d)\s+(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)$/
```

You can customize it to your needs I guess.

**Explanation:**

```
    "
^              # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
                  # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      0              # Match the character “0” literally
         ?              # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      [1-9]          # Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9”
   |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      1              # Match the character “1” literally
      [012]          # Match a single character present in the list “012”
)
/              # Match the character “/” literally
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
                  # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      0              # Match the character “0” literally
         ?              # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      [1-9]          # Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9”
   |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      [12]           # Match a single character present in the list “12”
      \d             # Match a single digit 0..9
   |              # Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      3              # Match the character “3” literally
      [01]           # Match a single character present in the list “01”
)
/              # Match the character “/” literally
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
   \d             # Match a single digit 0..9
   \d             # Match a single digit 0..9
)
\s             # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +              # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
                  # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      [01]           # Match a single character present in the list “01”
         ?              # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      \d             # Match a single digit 0..9
   |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      2              # Match the character “2” literally
      [0-3]          # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “3”
)
:              # Match the character “:” literally
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
   [0-5]          # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5”
   \d             # Match a single digit 0..9
)
$              # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Comment: Why do your parenthetical groupings start with `(?:` instead of just `(`? How do those two extra characters change the regex logic?

Comment: @ean5533 Because I don't want to use them as backreferences, rather to simple use alternation and group various parts of the regex. If you remove the ?: you store every single parentheses into a backreference group, which in this case was not asked. The logic remains unchanged.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about that modifier. Thanks.

Comment: -1: does _not_ match month `10` and _would_ match month `00`, day `00` - a little too flexible to be practical (especially by not allowing dates in October)

Comment: @CodeJockey I didn't expect anything less from you. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: +1 (and removal of previous down-vote) I might not have noticed if my birthday wasn't in October; thanks for making that correction - I've +1'd in anticipation of you making this final correction: your last edit made the 10th or 20th of any month invalid - again, not so cool (but at least it's only 24 days out of the year, instead of 31 :D)

Comment: @CodeJockey It's getting late so forgive these silly mistakes :)